# XNextEvent throw BadAccess error with ButtonPressMask

Tags: c++, x11

This is my code, I'm using it to implement non-blocking global hotkeys behavior:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

typedef struct
{
    Display *display;
    Window window;
} X11Data;


void handle_focus(X11Data& x11data)
{
    int revert_to_return = 0;
    XGetInputFocus(x11data.display, &x11data.window, &revert_to_return);

    if (x11data.window != None)
    {
        long EventMask = FocusChangeMask; //working
        EventMask |= KeyPressMask; //working
        EventMask |= PointerMotionMask; //working
        //EventMask |= ButtonPressMask; //non-working, BadAccess ((

        XSelectInput(x11data.display, x11data.window, EventMask);
    }
}

void some_op(XEvent& ev)
{
    //event processing actions
    printf("type %d\n", ev.type);
    fflush(stdout);
}

void handle_event(X11Data& x11data)
{
    XEvent ev;
    XNextEvent(x11data.display, &ev);

    switch (ev.type)
    {
        case FocusOut:
        {
            x11data.window = None;
            break;
        }
        case KeyPress:
        {
            some_op(ev);
            break;
        }
        case MotionNotify:
        {
            some_op(ev);
            break;
        }
        case ButtonPress:
        {
            some_op(ev);
            break;
        }
        default: break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    X11Data x11data;
    x11data.display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    x11data.window = None;

    while (true)
    {
        if (x11data.window == None)
            handle_focus(x11data);
        else
            handle_event(x11data);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Everything is working fine, except case when *ButtonPressMask* flag is present - program halts in that case. I assume, that I'm allowed to listen keyboard, but not mouse. So who knows the root of the problem and/or how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other client already selected `ButtonPressMask`

From [protocol spec](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xproto/x11protocol.txt):

> Multiple clients can select input on the same window; their
>   event-masks are disjoint. When an event is generated, it will be
>   reported to all interested clients. However, only one client at a time
>   can select for SubstructureRedirect , only one client at a time can
>   select for ResizeRedirect, and only one client at a time can select
>   for ButtonPress. An attempt to violate these restrictions results in
>   an Access error.